# What is a lobe in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, planar-graphs

I've tried googling it, but nothing really shows up. I ask because I'm reading a Lemma from Douglas West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*.

> Let S = {x, y} be a separating 2-set of $G$. If $G$ is nonplanar, then adding the edge $xy$ to some $S$-lobe of $G$ yields a nonplanar graph.

I don't know what an $S$-lobe is.

Comment: Doug West wrote *Introduction to Graph Theory*. David West wrote *Introduction to Continental Philosophy*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from a flat text version of this book I found online:

"Note also that the proof uses the 
notion of S-lobe defined in Section 5.2."

"5.2.17. Definition. Let S be a set of vertices in a graph G. An S-lobe of G is 
an induced subgraph of G whose vertex set consists of S and the vertices 
of a component of G - S."

I'll leave understanding it to you, seen as I've not studied graph theory to that level presently. Hopefully that helps